# Backend for mobile app - which to use and why?

Tags: database, mobile, backend

I want to start developing an app for both the Android and iOS markets.
The application will be user based and will contain a pretty big list of places which will have to be updated in real time.

Some developers advised that I'm better off creating a backend of my own using MySQL and PHP (which is not my very strong suit), but some advised to avoid the hassle and go for something like http://parse.com.

Which way would you recommend going for?
I must mention that this is going to be my first native app in development which I plan on releasing to the market.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend go for parse.com, as it will take your all server side technology burden, I am using parse.com in my app which is available for iOS and Android, also they provide API which you can run in background thread and response is very quick.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.
I received the same suggestion in other communities, guess this is the way to go :)

Comment: Parse now is open source and you can either run it self-hosting wherever you want or using https://www.back4app.com

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for a BaaS myself. [Found this neat article that compares the best BaaS, with a photo sharing app,out there.](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20482/how-to-choose-the-best-backend-provider-for-your-ios-app-parse-vs-stackmob-vs-appcelerator-cloud-and-more) I think parse is pretty good and I am going to with it.

Answer (score 1):

**Popular BaaS providers:**

- Firebase
- AWS
- Back4App (Parse SDK)

**Others:**

- Mesosfer
- BaasBox
- Apache Usergrid
- Azure Mobile Services
- Apple CloudKit

[**Source here**](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/back-end-as-a-service-for-mobile-apps--cms-28154)